# Substituting column value if particular column exists in two DataFrames with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 2 data frames representing CSV files as such:

```
# 1.csv

id,email
1,someone@email.com
2,someoneelse@email.com
...
```

```
# 2.csv

id,email
3,someone@otheremail.com
4,someone@email.com
...
```

What I'm trying to do is to merge both tables into one `DataFrame` using `Pandas` based on whether a particular column (in this case column 2, `email`) is identical in both `DataFrame`s.
I need the merged DataFrame to choose the `id` from `2.csv`.

For example, using the sample data above, since the `email` column value `someone@email.com` exists in both CSVs, I need the merged DataFrame to output the following:

```
# 3.csv
id,email
4,someone@gmail.com
2,someoneelse@email.com
3,someone@otheremail.com
```

What I have so far is as follows:

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('/path/to/1.csv')

print("df1 has {} rows".format(len(df1.index)))
# "df1 has 14072 rows"

df2 = pd.read_csv('/path/to/2.csv')

print("df2 has {} rows".format(len(df2.index)))
# "df2 has 56766 rows"

join = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="email", how="inner")

print("join has {} rows".format(len(join.index)))
# "join has 321 rows"
```

The problem is that the `join` DataFrame produces only the rows where the `email` field exists in both DataFrames. What I expect is that the output DataFrame contain `56766 + 14072 - 321 = 70517` rows with the `id` values be the ones from `2.csv` when the `email` field is identical in both source DataFrames. I tried to change the `merge(how="left|right")` but the results are identical.

Comment: Use `how='outer'`.

Comment: Still got the same with `how='outer'`...

Answer (score 0):

```
from datatable import dt, f, by

df1 = dt.Frame("""
id,email
1,someone@email.com
2,someoneelse@email.com
""")
df1['csv'] = 1

df2 = dt.Frame("""
id,email
3,someone@otheremail.com
4,someone@email.com
""")
df2['csv'] = 2


df_all = dt.rbind(df1, df2)

df_result = df_all[-1, ['id'], by('email')]
```

Comment: Thanks, had some issues with installing `datatable` on my Macbook. Apparently it's not yet supported on Bi Sur.

Comment: @KobbiGal, datatable works fine on my MacBook with Big Sur.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by uploading the files to Google Spreadsheet and using`VLOOKUP`